# How to use Angular2 form validation directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have the following attribute directive to perform form validation. My `@NgModule` includes it in it's declarations array. My form is in a component's template. How would I add the `appCarrierFormValidation` attribute to my form to be able to use this directive and validate the inputs?

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCarrierFormValidation]'
})
export class CarrierFormValidationDirective {

  addCarrierForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.addCarrierForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i see your code within the custom validator for  `appCarrierFormValidation`?

Comment: I'm confused, `appCarrierFormValidation` is just the attribute selector to use in the template right?

Comment: Sorry, I miss out a few words before I edited it. Anyways, I misunderstood your question just now. Wait, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Where and when would you want those 2 FormControls to be validated? I.e, would you want the form fields to be validated immediately when the user keys in a value? Or upon submission of form?

Comment: I have a component, `AddCarriersComponent` whose template contains a form, `form [formGroup]="addCarrierForm"` This form contains those 2 controls that require validation.

Comment: why do you use Directive it's not a Component??????

Comment: @Eliseo I am using a directive it because I want to share it between multiple components

Comment: you can use as Child of any component. Your "directive" the only thing make it's create a FormGroup. Sorry, I can't imagine what do you want to get

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like this, I used in my project.

```
  import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

    export function appCarrierFormValidation(control: FormControl) {

        // change your logic to validate carrier
        let pattern = /[*\\/|":?><]/gi;
        //if validation fails, return error name & value of true
        if (pattern.test(control.value)) {
            return { validString: true };
        }
        //otherwise, if the validation passes, we simply return null
        return null;
    }
```

And use

```
name: ['', [Validators.required, appCarrierFormValidation]],
```

If you want to use formGroup

```
public appCarrierFormValidation() : ValidatorFn{
       return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
          const name= group.controls['name'];
          const email= group.controls['email'];
          // add your logic here
          if (name.value.length < 6 && email.value.indexOf('@') < 0) {
             email.setErrors({invalid: true});
          } else {
             email.setErrors(null);
          }
          return;
    };
 }
```

Update your code

```
 createForm() {
    this.addCarrierForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    })
    this.addCarrierForm .setValidators(this.appCarrierFormValidation())
  }
```

Comment: What is the pattern regular expression you're using? And in this method, I wouldn't need to add an attribute to the template?

Comment: This is a sample, you can change to your logic

Comment: I get a `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance` error in my template